# Tab Index JavaScript function unknown/unspecified error?

Tags: javascript, html

## NOTICE

**I already asked this question on my alt account David Vex; but that account is glitched out and I can't sign into it, with a StackOverflow server error with gibberish talking about ERROR:0x12084123 followed by server gibberish; so the only way to follow up with it is reasking it. Please Excuse any inconvienence.**

---

### Quote from Question (Alt Account)

## WORKABLE CODE

[**Better than JSFiddle!**](http://codepen.io/TheGamingHideout/pen/JoPVZw)

I'm trying to make a table with a tabindex for each element which onClick, it will activate the imageSelector function (unnamed). I got the code from my last question, which was given with no named function. It worked with the 'alert' variant, but I fit it for the function that I need to check the answer which, if the if(answer1.innerHTML == "Correct Answer"){document.getElementById("correctAnswer").addAttribute("display", "inline")} is active, it will know that the answer is the set correct one, and will set the image with the id="correctAnswer" to display, but then after 3 seconds it should go back to display="hidden" and re-activate the whole randomize sequence, if the button isn't already selected, which doesn't seem to work. I tried using a setTimeout() function to make it when the answer is correct/incorrect, it will set a delay to call the function that would make the image invisible and re-randomize the answers. I'll show the code, and re-explain each part after the code.

## HTML

```
  <div id="randomizer">
    <div id="wordOutput">
      <div id="button">
        <!-- This is the button that calls the getRandom() function to create the word. --><button id="myBtn">Randomize!</button><br>
        <caption>Click this button to generate a random word!
        </caption>
        <!-- This is apart of the Randomizer tool, which can be changed to fit the words. It will output the answers based on  -->
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="answers" class="answers">
      <table>
        <p id="outputNumber" class="outputNumber">Your word will go here; Click the Randomize Button!</p>
        <tr>
          <td class="output" id="output1" tabindex="1"></td>
          <td class="output" id="output2" tabindex="1"></td>
          <td class="output" id="output3" tabindex="1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="output" id="output4" tabindex="1"></td>
          <td class="output" id="output5" tabindex="1"></td>
          <td class="output" id="output6" tabindex="1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="output" id="output7" tabindex="1"></td>
          <td class="output" id="output8" tabindex="1"></td>
          <td class="output" id="output9" tabindex="1"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  <div id="checkAnswer">
    <img id="correctAnswer" src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1965/colorcons_smoke/128/checkmark.png" alt="correct" style="position: absolute; left: 100px; display: none;">
    <img id="incorrectAnswer" src="http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/1008/quiet/128/no.png" alt="incorrect" style="position: absolute; right: 100px; display: none;">
  </div>
  </div>
```

This lays out the whole sequence. outputNumber is where the number will be generated then converted to a word. The button div is simple; it's where the button is. The answers div holds the table, and each element is fitted with the id for the targetting, with the tabindex for making it clickable. The checkAnswer div holds the two hidden images.

#### CSS

Not really important; all it contains is Daneden's animate.css (3150 lines) of code plus 10 more lines for the coloring of the page...

## JavaScript

```
/* Has the words and their respectful answers. */
var words = [
  { word: "Fruits A-B", array: ["Apple", "Apricot", "Avacado", "Banana", "Breadfruit", "Bilberry", "Blackberry", "Blackcurrant", "Blueberry"] },
  { word: "Fruits B-C", array: ["Boysenberry", "Cantaloupe", "Currant", "Cherry", "Cherimoya", "Cloudberry", "Coconut", "Cranberry", "Cucumber"] },
  { word: "Fruits D-G", array: ["Damson", "Date", "Dragonfruit", "Durian", "Eggplant", "Elderberry", "Feijoa", "Fig", "Goji berry"] },
  { word: "Fruits G-K", array: ["Gooseberry", "Grape", "Grapefruit", "Guava", "Huckleberry", "Honeydew", "Jackfruit", "Jambul", "Kiwi fruit"] },
  { word: "Fruits K-M", array: ["Kumquat", "Lemon", "Lime", "Loquat", "Lychee", "Mango", "Marion berry", "Melon", "Miracle fruit"] },
  { word: "Fruits M-P", array: ["Mulberry", "Nectarine", "Nut", "Olive", "Orange", "Papaya", "Passionfruit", "Peach", "Pepper"] },
  { word: "Fruits P-Q", array: ["Pear", "Persimmon", "Physalis", "Plum", "Pineapple", "Pomegranate", "Pomelo", "Purple Mangosteen", "Quince"] },
  { word: "Fruits R-T", array: ["Raspberry", "Rambutan", "Salal berry", "Salmon berry", "Satsuma", "Star fruit", "Strawberry", "Tomarillo", "Tomato"] },
  { word: "Fruits U-Z", array: ["Ugli fruit", "Watermelon", "Bell pepper", "Chili pepper", "Clementine", "Mandarine", "Tangerine", "Blood Orange", "Rock Melon"] }
];
/* This function grabs the word that is outputted, then changes the answers based on that word. Change to your liking! */
function grabWord() {
  var word = document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML;
  var wordIndex;
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (words[i].word === word) {
      wordIndex = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    document.getElementById("output" + i).innerHTML = words[wordIndex].array[i-1];
  }
}
/* This function SHOULD be working, which it does if the function is something like alert(message) but with the function I need for the image visibility and such, it doesn't work; it doesn't even give me an answer. */
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
  cells[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    var word = document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML;
    var answer1 = document.getElementById("output1");
    var answer2 = document.getElementById("output2");
    var answer3 = document.getElementById("output3");
    var answer4 = document.getElementById("output4");
    var answer5 = document.getElementById("output5");
    var answer6 = document.getElementById("output6");
    var answer7 = document.getElementById("output7");
    var answer8 = document.getElementById("output8");
    var answer9 = document.getElementById("output9");
    if(word == "Fruits U-Z")  {
      if(answer1.innerHTML == "Ugli Fruit")  {
        document.getElementById("correctAnswer").setAttribute("display", "inline")
      }
      else  {
        document.getElementById("incorrectAnswer").setAttribute("display", "inline")
      }
    }
  })
}
```

I have it condensed as MUCH as possible, but for the grabWord() function, I have to keep it that long, so that each word can have answers changed manually. It's set to what it is now for example purposes.

## ERROR/PROBLEM

When I click on the answer that would match the last part that would check if its right or not, it does nothing. So I check the dev console (F12 in-browser) and see no error.

Any ideas?

## KEEP IN MIND

I AM USUALLY BAD AT INCLUDING DETAILS/INFORMATION. IF YOU NEED MORE DETAILS, PLEASE COMMENT POLITELY, I WILL ADD AS MUCH INFO NEEDED POSSIBLE.

Comment: Try reducing all of your code to **just** replicate your error. 1) You might find a solution whilst doing that. 2) It helps us narrow in on your issue without dealing with all the distraction of your entire page. The more succinct you can make your questions, the more responses you're likely to get. Cheers!

Comment: @j08691 Because other parts of the code had it; it just wasn't included. Let me fix that.

Comment: The comment that starts, "This function should be working ..." is before a section of code that is *not a function*.

Comment: Also as a general coding rule, if you find yourself typing a list of variables with names like "answer1", "answer2", and so on, you should probably start thinking in terms of an **array**. There's a tremendous amount of needlessly duplicated code there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took a look at your code ... it is working.  However, you are setting the attribute "display" to "inline"; if you inspect the element for correct or incorrect answer this is NOT in the style ... adjustment below.

Also, you are only given a correct or incorrect when on Fruits U-Z and there is NO correct answer ... you, in this case, are comparing "Ugli fruit" in the array with "Ugli Fruit" as a string.

```
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
  cells[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    var word = document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML;
    var answer1 = document.getElementById("output1");
    var answer2 = document.getElementById("output2");
    var answer3 = document.getElementById("output3");
    var answer4 = document.getElementById("output4");
    var answer5 = document.getElementById("output5");
    var answer6 = document.getElementById("output6");
    var answer7 = document.getElementById("output7");
    var answer8 = document.getElementById("output8");
    var answer9 = document.getElementById("output9");
    console.log(word, answer1.innerHTML);
    if(word == "Fruits U-Z")  {
      if(answer1.innerHTML == "Ugli Fruit")  {
        document.getElementById("correctAnswer").setAttribute("style", "display:inline; position:absolute; left:100px;");
        document.getElementById("incorrectAnswer").setAttribute("style", "display:none; position:absolute; right:100px;");
      }
      else  {
                document.getElementById("correctAnswer").setAttribute("style", "display:none; position:absolute; left:100px;");
document.getElementById("incorrectAnswer").setAttribute("style", "display:inline; position:absolute; right:100px;");
      }
    }
  });
}
```